# UNAUTHENTICATED error when trying to access API in Spring deployed in GKE

Tags: spring, postman, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an API application deployed in Google Kubernetes Engine. The application is using firestore as its DB. When I try to call the API (both from Postman and browser), I got HTTP error 500. This is what it says in the log:

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication 
credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid 
authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign- 
in/web/devconsole-project. at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533) ~[grpc-
api-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2] at 
io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:460
) ~[grpc-stub-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2] at 
io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:426) ~[grpc-core-
1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2] at 
io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66) ~[grpc-core-
1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2] at 
io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:689) ~
[grpc-core-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2] at 
io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$900(ClientCallImpl.java:5
77) ~[grpc-core-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2] at 
io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(Client
CallImpl.java:751) ~[grpc-core-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2] at 
io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(Clien
tCallImpl.java:740) ~[grpc-core-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2] at 
io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[grpc-core-
1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2] at 
io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) ~[grpc-core-
1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2] at 
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) 
~[na:na] at 
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) 
~[na:na] at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

This is how roughly my Spring application looks like:

### MainApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "package.name.here" })
@EnableReactiveFirestoreRepositories
public class UserApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

### RestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserAPI {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public Flux<UserService> getAllUsers() {
        return userService.findAll();
    }
}
```

### UserService

```
@Component
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public Flux<User> findAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

### UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends FirestoreReactiveRepository<User> {
    Mono<User> findByUsername(String username);
    Mono<User> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

I have configured Postman Authorisation as guided [here](https://www.postman.com/speeding-resonance-133102/workspace/google-cloud-api/documentation/12689164-9400e5f3-afac-4759-afe4-630a3842b2eb) from the official documentation but it still gives the error above.

I'm using my google account, which is the owner of the project when requesting for access token on Postman.

Could anyone help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible subset of your code. Are you using Google's Firestore SDK and Application Default Credentials? If so, you've 2 options. Either mount a Service Account key into a Kubernetes Secret and reference it through an environment variable. Or use Workload Identity.

Comment: @DazWikin hi, I've edited my post. Is the credentials that you're talking about the credentials i need to setup in the Spring application itself to access firestore? I might have only login with gcloud in my machine, but I haven't setup anything in the application itself.

Comment: When you run code on Google Cloud Platform, it needs to auth as an identity. It is recommended that you use a Service Account as the identity for software.The account will need to be configured with sufficient IAM permissions. In the case of GKE, there's an extra step to expose the identity to the Pods in the cluster. You can read about the general principle [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform).

Comment: Google provides a Google-only solution too that may better serve your needs called [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity)

Comment: @DazWilkin - Can you please compile your comments into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

When you run code on Google Cloud Platform, it needs to auth as an identity.

It is recommended that you use a [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#what_are_service_accounts) as the identity for software.

The account will need to be configured with suitable IAM permissions. For example, to read from Firestore, the Service Account will neeed [`roles/datastore.viewer`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#datastore-roles).

> **NOTE** For historical reasons, Firestore IAM roles include the prefix `datastore`. This is because [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore) is one of Google Cloud Platform's original services and its functionality was expanded to include the functionality that [Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore) provides.

In the case of [Kubernetes Engine (GKE)](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine), an extra step is needed to expose the (Cloud Platform Service Account) identity so that it is accessible to the Pods in the cluster.

There are 2 ways you can do this:

1. Mount GCP Service Account key as a Kubernetes Secret in a Pod. This approach will work across any Kubernetes distribution. See [Authenticating to Google Cloud with Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform)
2. Google provides a more elegant albeit Google-only solution too that may better serve your needs called [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity).